# Bash optarg fails to spot missing arguments

Tags: bash

I am inexperienced with bash shell scripting, and have run into a problem with bash `optarg`

Here's a small script to reproduce the problem:

```
#!/bin/sh

while getopts ":a:b:"  opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    a ) echo "a=$OPTARG"
     ;;
    b ) echo "b=$OPTARG"
      ;;
    \? ) echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG" 1>&2 
      ;;
    : ) echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG requires an argument" 1>&2
  esac
done
```

When I try this:

```
./args.sh -a av -b bv
```

I get the expected result:

```
a=av
b=bv
```

But when I omit the argument for -a:

```
/args.sh -a -b bv
```

I get this unfortunate result:

```
a=-b
```

When I would expect an error to show that the value of -a is missing.

It seems to have taken the -b argument as the value for -a.
Have I done something wrong & how can I achieve the expected behaviour?

Comment: *When I would expect an error to show that the value of -a is missing.* Why? Here `/args.sh -a -b bv`, the option argument for `-a` is `-b`; that's not an application error

Comment: you probably understand what I want to achieve. Can you offer any positive advice?

Comment: @NickJ Why do you think `-b` shouldn't be a valid argument to `-a`? `getopts` simply isn't equipped to restrict valid argument values. An option either takes no argument, or a single arbitrary string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only positive advice is how do you treat *But when I omit the argument for `'-a'`*, you cannot just skip to the next subsequent option. By convention `getopts a:` means you are expecting to an provide an arg value for the flag defined.

So even for the omitting case, you need to define an empty string which means the value for the arg is not defined i.e.

```
-a '' -b bv
```

Or if you don't expect the `-a` to get any arg values, better change the option string to not receive any as `:ab:`.

Any other ways of working around by checking if the `OPTARG` for `-a` is does not contain `-` or other hacks are not advised as it does not comply with the `getopts()` work flow.

Answer (score 1):

`getopts` doesn't support such detection. So there's no way to do that with `getopts`.

You can probably write a loop around the arguments instead. something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

check_option()
{
    case $1 in
        -*)
            return 1
        ;;
    esac

    return 0
}

for opt in $@; do
  case ${opt} in
    -a) shift
        if check_option $1; then
            echo "arg for -a: $1"
            shift
        else
            echo "Invalid option -a"
        fi
     ;;
    -b) shift
        if check_option $1; then
            echo "arg for -b: $1"
            shift
        else
            echo "Invalid option -b"
        fi
     ;;
  esac
done
```